# Add a select box with option as Shopify metafield content type

Tags: shopify, customization

Is there a way to add a new custom content type to metafields in shopify?

The available content types are color, date, date and time..etc
But what I need is a select with 3 predefined option similar to product type select in Shopify admin

[image]

Comment: yes go to Shopify store settings and create a meta field of a product there you will see the option to show a select box with predefined values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings > metafields > products > add definition
select type as single-line text and used a rule limit to preset choices.
[image: new meta field for custom content type]